# How can I change the loss function when the shape of my data changes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Since my data is too large, I use `pd.read_csv('',chunksize=)`. I am using `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function, however, on the last chunk, I have just one target. So I get the error:

> You are passing a target array of shape (2110, 1) while using as loss
>   `categorical_crossentropy`.

Now I know I can use `binary_crossentropy`. So this is what I did.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data, train_labels, shuffle=True, test_size=0.3)
if y_train.shape[1] == 1:
   loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
else:
   loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

My data is one-hot encoded. How can I resolve this error? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

My target for the last chunk looks like:

```
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       ...,
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

My X_train :

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0, ...,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  7,  0,  0],
       ...,
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 22,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  5,  0,  1]])
```

My way of encoding labels:

```
    labels = np.array(labels)
    train_data = docs_encoded.astype(int)
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(labels)
    encoded_labels = encoder.transform(labels)
    train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to learn two tasks (binary and multiclass classification) using the same model. That is not possible, unless each example has two targets: 1 for binary and one for multiclass classification. What you can do is to use multiclass classification, using the 'categorical_crossentropy' as your loss function, but process your labels accordingly. If your last chunk has one target, just one-hot-encode it like the rest of your targets.

**UPDATE**
If you have 789 unique classes, and you last chun contains labels as you said:

```
# I'm creating a mock label array for the last chunk.
import numpy as np
last_chunk_labels = np.array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
categorical_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(a, 789)
```

your last chunk categorical labels would look something like this:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

where each row has 789 elements with 0 everywhere else, and 1 at the index for the class label.

Comment: Adding binary_crossentropy was an adaptation to the original problem: `You are passing a target array of shape (2110, 1) while using as loss categorical_crossentropy.`. Just using catgorical_crossentropy isn't helping. How could I resolve that error? Also, the whole data is one-hot encoded.

Comment: As I said, turn the targets in the last chunk to one-hot as well. For example if your target is 1 and you have 10 different categories, change it to [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and so on..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you look at the updated question? I am changing the text labels using labelencoder() and the using to_categorical.

Comment: How many classes do you have? what do your other labels look like?

Comment: I have 789 unique classes, divided into chunks. My other labels are as arrays. Please see the updated question.